# Can't start Android calendar intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, calendar

I'm trying to add an event to Android Calendar, however intent can't be applied to startActivity() for some reason.

Here is a code:

```
    public void addEventCalendarEvent(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
    intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
    intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
    intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

And error is marked red on startActivity(intent):
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srL7A.png)

What could be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of using startActivity() within Adapter without context. When I used `view.getContext.startActivity(intent)` everything started to work!

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend from `Activity` instead of `ActivityCompat`.

The ActivityCompat's `startActivity` needs three parameters:

```
startActivity(Activity activity, Intent intent, Bundle options)
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer! Unfortunately, I'm using this code in recyclerView adapter. Have no idea how to perform this solution there...